Is it possible a loop based on custom fields in Bricks Builder?
Is it possible a loop based on custom fields in a Wordpress Theme like Bricks Builder?
Right now I have a custom post type “Groups” and a custom post type “Characters”.
In every character post I have picked what group they are connected to via a custom field (connected_group). The Custom field is a list of all post titles.
Both custom post types and custom fields are made with ACF (free version).
On each group, I would like to display all the characters connected to that group.
Is this doable?
So far I have been able to make a list of all in the custom post type “characters”.
However I can not figure out how to only show the “characters” with a specific field.
I have tried with meta query in Bricks and some more custom code.
But the only thing I have success showing is the list for custom post type for all characters.
The custom Field
When setting it up in with Bricks Builders Meta Query - I cant get it to work
When setting it up with Bricks Builders Query Editor - I cant't get it to work

Are you sure the meta key for the group field is {acf_connected_group} and not just acf_connected_group without curly brackets?
